# How to disable escaping using XMLOutputter

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I use XMLOutputter to write xml file to use it then in android. When the file is written, string

```
<string name="sname"><u>Text</u></string>
```

is written as

```
<string name="sname">&lt;u&gt;Text&lt;u&gt;</string>
```

I read "<u>Text<u>" from database and then put it into jdom Document. Then I write the document using

```
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8");
outputter.output(doc, writer);
writer.close();
```

How can I prevent escaping and put the exact string from database to file? (I want to have '<', not `&lt;` there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to prevent escaping by:

- Extending `XMLOutputer` and overriding `escapeElementEntities` method

  ```
  XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat()) {
          @Override
          public String escapeElementEntities(String str) {
              return str;
          }
      };
  Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8");
  outputter.output(doc, writer);
  writer.close();
  ```

I found this [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1248248)

- Setting custom `EscapeStrategy` on the `Format` to prevent escaping certain characters

Either way you should be careful to produce a valid XML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, MJar. It works. I tried this with jdom2 and it didn't worked, because XMLOutputter in jdom2 is final. I downloaded first version and now it works.