# JDOM : XMLOutputter line breaks in attribute replaced by &#xA;

Tags: xml, jdom

I have an XML document with an element that looks something like this:

```
<element attribute="this
has
line
breaks"/>
```

When I'm parsing it, this is outputted as:

```
<element attribute="this&#xA;has&#xA;line&#xA;breaks"/>
```

It's because, JDOM normalizes all the attribute values at its way, when it's not in an attribute (not in quotes), the value is well outputted.
So I would like to know if it's possible to get back the same xml with its line breaks.

Thank you and I hope you understood my english :3

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359198/how-to-disable-escaping-using-xmloutputter)

Comment: Thank you very much, I resolved my problem by overriding the method escapeAttributeEntities of XMLOutputter.

Comment: Anytime, glad it helped  :)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem this way, if it can help

```
XMLOutputter sortie = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat().setExpandEmptyElements(true)) {
                    @Override
                    public String escapeAttributeEntities(String str) {
                        str = str.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
                        return str;
                    }
};
```